# Web API 2 Put from one controller calls Post from other controller not working

Tags: .net

I have a WebAPI project that has two models, Sensors and Sensor log. The sensor has a state and a name and the Sensor Log has name, state and a date property. All of this on their own works fine.

My issues is when I put to the sensor I also would like to post to the sensor log. That way I can update the log while keeping the current state for the sensor itself. Right now I can put to the sensors and post to the sensor logs from their own controller but when I try to call the post from the sensor log from the put method of the sensor i get an unexpected result.

Instead of a put on the sensor and a post on the sensor log I get a post on both the sensor and the sensor log. ie. the put no long updates the sensor but creates a new one in the sensor table and then associates the new sensor to the sensor log that is posted. What could be causing this ? 
 public async void PutSensor(int id, Sensor sensor)
        {

```
        db.Entry(sensor).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {

        }

        // return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50293/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            // HTTP POST
            var log = new SensorLog() { StateId = sensor.StateId, SensorId = sensor.Id };
            HttpResponseMessage responsee = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/SensorLogs/", log);

        }        
    }
```

Comment: I edited the question and added code below